# How can I pass the JSON values as parameters in the method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I'm working on Nunit's data-driven method and I'm stuck with this issue. I want to pass values from the JSON file as the parameters in the test method. '[I've done this much so far but it's giving me an error that says: can not convert from 'Newtonsoft.Json.LinqToken' to 'string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqtub.png)

```
public class TestData: BasePage 
{ 
    static JObject? data = ReadJson(@"jsconfig1.json");  
    static JToken? url = data.SelectToken("url").Value<string>(); 
    static JToken? username = data.SelectToken("username").Value<string>(); 
    static JToken? password = data.SelectToken("password").Value<string>(); 

    public void Login_Method()
    {
        driver.Url = url;
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("username")).SendKeys(username);
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys(password);
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("login")).Click();

        driver.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that the `jsconfig1.json` is like this:

```
var json = """
        {
            "url": "https://www.google.com",
            "username": "guest",
            "password": "pwd123"
        }
        """;
```

Then one way among others is to create a dto:

```
public record Config(string Url, string Username, string Password);
```

and then to deserialize using `Text.Json`:

```
var config = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Config>(json, new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });

string username = config.Username;
string password = config.Password;
```

Finally because the `SendKeys` method requires string as input you can use the above strings in order to submit the user/pass values

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure, your jsconfig1.json contains required properties then you can use string instead of nullable JToken. It seems like in your case the issue is with conversion JToken values to string. As said, you can use string version of it.

```
public class TestData : BasePage 
{ 
    static JObject data = ReadJson(@"jsconfig1.json");  
    static string url = data.SelectToken("url").ToString(); 
    static string username = data.SelectToken("username").ToString(); 
    static string password = data.SelectToken("password").ToString(); 

    public void Login_Method()
    {
        driver.Url = url;
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("username")).SendKeys(username);
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys(password);
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("login")).Click();

        driver.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Sir Asif. It worked for me. I was stuck with the Jtoken issue for so long.